# How to make a filter component like Google chrome find (Cntrl + F) that detects the text and change it's background color

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

world, 
last day I wanted to make a search/filter component that behaves as google chrome find component like below :

[image]

But the problems are :

1. I can find the word and replace it with a `<span class="text-found">${CHOOSEN_WORD}</span>` but only first three letters
2. I can't reverse it (remove the style from the letters)

This is my last efforts :

i have a component named `Content` like so it has :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const Content = ({ pattern }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    searchText(pattern);
  }, [pattern]);


  const searchText = pattern => {
    let list = document.querySelectorAll(".text-row");

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let res = list[i].innerHTML.replace(
          new RegExp(pattern, "g"),
          `<span class="text-found">${pattern}</span>`
        );
        document.querySelectorAll(".text-row")[i].innerHTML = res;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography className="text-row">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </Typography>
      <Typography className="text-row">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

and this is my result :

[image]

Comment: How much text do you plan to have? And show us you regex pattern matching rule

Comment: this is my pattern => new RegExp(pattern, "g"),
and then i replace it with a span with that text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucky You, I was exactly working on a project in which I used Material UI in it, so I was able to use your component in my own codebase and debug it a little bit.

[image]

- I use typescript so some types are added to your code and if you are not familiar with Typescript it might seem a little strange.
- About the reverse process, the key is to clean up things when your pattern is changed.
- I used an internal state for debugging purposes you can which of course replace it with React props.

A rewritten version of your component that just works:

```
const Test = () => {
  const [pattern, setPattern] = useState<string>("");
  useEffect(() => {
    let list = document.querySelectorAll(".text-row");
    const searchText = (pattern: string) => {
      if (!pattern) return;
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let res = list[i].innerHTML.replace(
          new RegExp(pattern, "g"),
          `<span class="text-found">${pattern}</span>`
        );
        document.querySelectorAll(".text-row")[i].innerHTML = res;
      }
    };
    searchText(pattern);
    const cleanUp = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let res = list[i].innerHTML
          .replace(new RegExp('<span class="text-found">', "g"), "")
          .replace(new RegExp("</span>", "g"), "");
        document.querySelectorAll(".text-row")[i].innerHTML = res;
      }
    };
    return cleanUp;
  }, [pattern]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setPattern(e.target.value)} />
      <Typography className="text-row">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </Typography>
      <Typography className="text-row">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```